# How come stratification doesn't improve fit

Tags: matlab, classification, decision-tree, training-data

### Introduction

Stratification is when you train a model per subset of your data according to a categorical feature (e.g. one classifier for man and one for woman, when classifying for a disease).

### Expected Training Error

I would expect that Stratification will always improve the training error (aka fit) as I actually introduced double degrees of freedom (if the number of parameters is X now the number is potentially 2X). Another way to look at it is that I increase the hypothesis space.

### Observed Training Error

However, when I test my performance (using Matlab's TreeBagger as base learner) I get actually worse training-error performance when I employ stratification compared to the case where I don't.

Can someone please explain this phenomenon?

Thanks,
Hanan

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess: Data is correlated. If you have data A and B and their values are correlated and are not (or just slightly) dependant of being part of A or part of B, then you expect to have worse results.

---

**Extreme example:** You have 2 dice, you roll each of them twice.

If you try to get the mean value of rolling dice and you use both data together, you will get better results than if you suppose that each dice is different and get the mean of each dice. This is because you assumed that data is dependant of dice, where it is not.

---

I don't know your application nor your data dimensionality/amount, but I hope this little example gives you the insight of why this could happen.

Comment: Hi @Ander Biguri, thank you for your attention. My question was about TRAINING ERROR, so your dice example is not very convincing. The computed mean equals the sample mean so that fit is 100% correct either if you split or not. Notice I am talking about splitting the samples and not the features.

Comment: Mmmmm you may be righ, I am not an expert. @HananShteingart